# Collision c++ 2d game, preventing player from entering tile

Tags: c++, collision, sfml

I've tried for several days and spent hours searching the web to no avail. I'm having trouble with collision, i can detect the collision but my problem is preventing the player from entering the tile. I've tried all i can think of. I'm detecting the collision of my tilemap using 1 for solid and 0 for passive

```
for(int i = 0; i < tiles.size(); i++)
    {
        if(colMap[tiles[i].y][tiles[i].x] == 1)
        {
            myrect.setFillColor(sf::Color::Red);
            collide = true;
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            collide = false;
            break;
        }
    }
```

This works ok, my text player turns red once colliding with the tile but i cant figure out how to prevent the player entering that tile to begin with, my current setup i tried to disable movement but all that happens is the player enters the collision is set to true and the controls disabled which results in the player stuck completely.

my current movement is very basic

```
if(sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Left))
{
    if(walking == false)
    {
        //colCheck();
        if(!collide)
        {
        nextspot = x - tilesize;
        move[LEFT] = true;
        walking = true;
        }else
        {
            std::cout << "Collsion!" << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: If movement results in collision, restore players position to what it was before collision. Or, *if* a movement would result in collision, do not move player.

Comment: This would have been better suited for Game Development (dot) Stack Exchange.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how are you drawing your map?  What OS?

Comment: That `for` loop makes no sense; you set out to check every tile, then abort after checking the first one. I don't see how it can work, unless `tiles[0]` happens to have the same color as the tile in question. And your "current movement" doesn't seem to involve changing `x`.

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to always record where your player has been one turn before:

```
static int prevY, prevX;

for(int i = 0; i < tiles.size(); i++)
{
    if(colMap[tiles[i].y][tiles[i].x] == 1)
    {
        myrect.setFillColor(sf::Color::Red);
        collide = true;

        /* Return Player To Where He's Been */
        colMap[prevY][prevX] = 1;

        break;
    }
    else
    {
        collide = false;
        break;
    }
}
```

Another method would be to look ahead before moving:

```
for(int i = 0; i < tiles.size(); i++)
{
    /* Look Ahead (Depends On Which Way He's Trying To Go)*/
    if(colMap[tiles[i].y + newY][tiles[i].x + newX] == 1)
    {
        myrect.setFillColor(sf::Color::Red);
        willCollide = true;
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        willCollide = false;
        break;
    }
}
```

`newY` and `newX` can be `-1`, `0`, or `1`.  If either `newY` or `newX` `!= 0`, the other has to be `0`.

Comment: Thanks for the code, you gave me the answer i needed, the code by its self didnt work for me but checking ahead to see if the player will collide or not was exactly what i was looking for. I combined checking collision with movement and it works perfect. thank you