# Tilemap Collision SFML C++

Tags: c++, dictionary, collision, sfml, tile

I've spent many frustrating hours and cannot figure this out, i understand collision and have it working until i try to implement gravity, i cant seem to set the player position after it hits the tile map, falling through the ground is my problem, x axis a variation of the following code works fine

```
if (background.colMap[tiles[i].y][tiles[i].x] == 1)
    {
        playerSpeed.y = -0.f;
        playerSprite.setPosition(playerSprite.getPosition().x, playerSprite.getPosition().y - 1);
        inAir = false;
    }
```

I though by reducing the speed to 0 and bumping the player back 1 pixel would work, but all it does is the player sprite bounces up and down

Comment: This isn't enough information or code to tell you what the problem is, but you're probably either going back to a falling state, or have a one-off problem.

Comment: dauphic is right, we really need a working minimal code example to really solve the problem, but I still gave it a try, hope it helps!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Collision c++ 2d game, preventing player from entering tile](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20777875/collision-c-2d-game-preventing-player-from-entering-tile)

Answer (score 2):

Given the above information, I assume you're making a side-scrolling game, and your character is colliding with the top of a tile.

That said, the first thing you need to understand is that you're not supposed to adjust the position of the character after it moved but before it moved. The character is never supposed to be in a position that is "illegal" in your game. Even for a fraction of a second.

You have the power to see the future (at least in your own game), use it at will! Always be one step ahead.

## How to find the right place?

Basic algebra!

Here's the situation.

[image: Collision Algebra]

The goal here is to find where the green and red dotted line cross the small blue dotted line (which represent the ground).

First, we need to find the equation of our character (black dot) trajectory, which should looks like: `y = ax + b`.

Where the slope `a = (Y2 - Y1)/(X2 - X1)` and `b = y - ax`.

In our example case, the equation is `y = -2x + 10`. We just need to know what is the value of X when `Y = 3`, which we can find with `x = (y - b) / a` and in our case, `x = (3 - 10) / (-2) = 3.5`.

So we now know that our character will be intersecting with the floor at `(3.5, 3)` and that's where we will put the character.

## Flaws of your current technique

When you collide, you put the character up 1 pixel if I understand correctly your code.

Imagine that your character is going really fast and in one update of his position, he gets from a valid position to an invalid one, 25 pixels below the ground. With your current technique, it will take at least 25 position updates to get back on the ground or maybe just 25 collision detection loops, but still, it's not very efficient.

Another thing, you seem to be looping every possible tiles in the level, so that's probably mostly empty tiles and/or full ground (inaccessible) tiles, which is a big overhead on what you really need.

The best option would be to store the coordinates of collidable tiles and just iterate those tiles.

If you have a screen of, let's say 50 x 50 tiles, and there are only 25 collidable tiles, you're still checking `50 * 50 - 25 = 2475` tiles, and these are 2475 unnecessary checks. But obviously, that's not the reason why you are having trouble, even those 2475 unnecessary checks won't break the logic.

And just to play with the numbers, since our character is 25 pixels below, we'll loop 25 times 2500 tiles, which is 62500 checks, instead of `25 * 25 = 625` with a collidable tile collection, or just 25 checks with the math stuff.

Comment: my player size is 64px tall by 32px wide, each tile is 32x32px. Im only checking collision of the tiles the player touches by getting the four corners of the player and seeing what tiles it touches. what i cant seem to figure out is how to calculate the if the player touches a collision tile before it does. I appreciate your example but im struggling to grasp it

Comment: You could use the method I described with the 4 corners of your character rectangle to see if they collide with a tile.